# order book matching program/algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to create a order book matching program which will have buy and sell orders.

```
Test Cases:
1. An order to buy can match to sell order if both have same quantity and same price
2. An order to buy can match to sell order if both have same quantity but buy order has greater price
3. An order to buy cannot match to sell order if both have same quantity but buy order has less price
```

I have following Order class

```
class Order:

    def __init__(self, order_id, order_type, order_price, order_quantity):
        self.order_id = order_id
        self.order_type = order_type
        self.order_price = order_price
        self.order_quantity = order_quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Order [order_id: {self.order_id}]"
```

and this will be my input:

```
order_input = [
    Order("1", "buy", 100, 10),
    Order("2", "buy", 120, 25),
    Order("3", "sell", 100, 25),
    Order("4", "sell", 100, 15),
    Order("5", "buy", 100, 15),
    Order("6", "buy", 100, 15),
]
```

> I want the following output:
>
> Order matched:
>   source order:  Order [order_id: 3]
>   matched order: Order [order_id: 2]
>
> Order matched:
>   source order:  Order [order_id: 5]
>   matched order: Order [order_id: 4]
>
> Order matched:
>   source order:  Order [order_id: 6]
>   matched order: Order [order_id: 4]

Comment: The problem is known as a [maximal matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) in a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). It can be solved using a [network flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) algorithm.

Comment: There are various solutions available with "basic" (for this paradigm) research, depending on your business rules for matching.  You neglected to specify those, or to show your solutions so far.

Comment: Thanks, can someone tell the working solution?

Comment: separate them to two sorted lists o(NlogN), one for sell one for buy, not sure what are the demands but suppose you want to pay the least,  start with the highest sell price, search for the closest equal or bigger buy price, for all the sell, again O(NlogN).